# Trying to get the MediaRecorder to reset and also to continue running when I change to a different class

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder

Currently I am facing three issues:

1. Getting the MediaRecorder to reset instead of release. 
   I think i need to create a new instance of the MediaRecorder and release() it as well, but I do not know where.
2. I want it to keep recording audio until the phone dies and even when the user changes to a different screen (i.e. going to a new class). 
   I have tried to google this but do not know how to achieve it.

Edit - I figured out how to use SimpleDateFormat!
Edit 2 - Realised I need to create a started service for my 2nd issue.

My code is as follows

Class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Drugs extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView myBrowser;
    MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private static String audioFilePath;
    public boolean isRecording = false;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public boolean isPlaying = false;
    SimpleDateFormat simpledate;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drugs);



        myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/drugs.html");
        myBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        Button btndrugslaw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.drugslaw);




        btndrugslaw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentdruglaw = new Intent(Drugs.this, DrugLaw.class);
                startActivity(intentdruglaw);
            }
        });}


    public void RecordButton (View view) {
        if(mRecorder == null){
            audioFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + simpledate 
                    + "/myaudio.3gp";
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        }
        if (isRecording) {
            try{
                stopRecording();
                isRecording = false;
                ((Button)view).setText("Start Recording");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try{
                startRecording();
                isRecording = true;
                ((Button)view).setText("Stop Recording");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void startRecording() throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
        mRecorder.prepare();
        MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording() throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.reset();
    }

    public void StartPlaying(View view) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
        }
        if (isPlaying) {
            try {
                stopPlaying();
                isPlaying = false;
                ((Button)view).setText("Play Audio");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try{
                startPlaying();
                isPlaying = true;
                ((Button)view).setText("Stop Audio");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    public void startPlaying() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stopPlaying () throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered Services for the second issue?

Comment: @birra I am completely new to coding so no... I will look into it though.

Comment: You can start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: @birraa thanks for that link, figured out how to run a service to run MediaRecorder now im getting a bit confused as to achieve my goal! I think its time for a new post